# get a datetime from mongo and push it to the array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have documents with the following props:

```
{
   'published_date': '2020/03/10 07:20:09',
   'relationships': [
       {'rel_name': 'HAS_REL'},
       {'rel_name': 'HAS_NO_REL'},
    ]
}
```

I want to add in each field of `relationships` that has as `rel_name` the value of `HAS_REL` the value of the published date as the property dict. The document will become as follows:

```
{
   'published_date': '2020/03/10 07:20:09',
   'relationships': [
       { 'rel_name': 'HAS_REL'
         'date': 2020,03,10,07,20,09
       },
       {'rel_name': 'HAS_NO_REL'},
    ]
}
```

So far my query looks something like this:

```
TEST_COLLECTION.update_one(
  {'_id': ObjectId(document_id)},
  {'$set': {'relationships.$[elem].date': {'$dateFromString': '$published_date'}}},
  False,
  False,
  None,
  [{'elem.rel_name': 'HAS_RELATIONSHIP'}],
)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$dateFromString' in 'parsed.relationships.1.date.$dateFromString' is not valid for storage.
```

any ideas?

**UPDATE**
With the initial answer, I've updated the query such as follows:

```
TEST_COLLECTION.update_one(
    {'_id': ObjectId(document_id)},
    [
        {'$set': {
            'relationships': {
                '$let': {
                    'vars': {
                        'date': { '$dateFromString': { 'dateString': '$published_date', format: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" } }
                    },
                    'in': {
                        '$map': {
                            'input': "$relationships",
                            'in': {
                                '$cond': {
                                      'if': { '$eq': ["$$this.rel_name", "HAS_REL"] },
                                      'then': { '$mergeObjects': ["$$this", { 'date': "$$date" }] },
                                      'else': "$$this"
                                   }
                                }
                             }
                          }
                       }
                    }
              }
         }
    ]
)
```

However, it seems I'me not getting a correct document:

> InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was
> built-in function format

Comment: Try `"format": `

Comment: such a stupid mistake ^^ too many hours coding, thanks @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html)

You have to specify `format` field, unless you use default format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ"`. Storing date/time values as string is usually a design flaw.

So, it must be

```
{'$dateFromString': { dateString: '$published_date', format: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" } }
```

Note, the time is considered at UTC time. Set field `timezone` to specify the time zone if required.

Be aware, `$dateFromString()` is an aggregation function, so you must use

```
TEST_COLLECTION.update_one(
   { '_id': ObjectId(document_id) },
   [
      {
         $set: {
            relationships: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$relationships",
                  in: {
                     $cond: {
                        if: { $eq: ["$$this.rel_name", "HAS_REL"] },
                        then: {
                           $mergeObjects: [
                              "$$this",
                              {
                                 date: {
                                    $dateFromString: {
                                       dateString: '$published_date',
                                       format: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        else: "$$this"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

or another style:

```
TEST_COLLECTION.update_one(
   { '_id': ObjectId(document_id) },
   [
      {
         $set: {
            relationships: {
               $let: {
                  vars: {
                     date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: '$published_date', format: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" } }
                  },
                  in: {
                     $map: {
                        input: "$relationships",
                        in: {
                           $cond: {
                              if: { $eq: ["$$this.rel_name", "HAS_REL"] },
                              then: { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { date: "$$date" }] },
                              else: "$$this"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried for your answer. However, with pymongo this doesnt' seem to work, I've updated the question